# What's the usage of different scrollbar attributes applied on the multiline text view in android?

Tags: attributes, scrollbar, textview, inspector, android

Android Studio(AS) 3.4's attributes inspector has various attributes for providing scrolling features to our multiline text views. There is supposed to be an attribute called scrollIndicators [none, top, bottom, left, right, start, end] in the attributes inspector which is used to display a visual cue to indicate that the text is scrollable. This attribute is not showing in the inspector window. However, setting the scrollbar's value to 'vertical' seems to have accomplished what scrollIndicators was meant for. 
Why are some attributes not displayed even under 'All Attributes'?

Also, the purpose of scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack and scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack is unclear.

I checked for these but couldn't find any proper usage and scrollIndicators are also not documented officially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked that although some attributes do not show up in the attributes window, but we can add them manually inside our layout file.